# Available technologies for Mobile Web Development

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, spring-mobile

Recently we have finished the development of our application and we have used `Spring , Hibernate,Jquery` etc in it.

Now today my manager came to me and asked , hey we have to develop a mobile version of our application so that it can work efficiently on mobile devices. He was more focusing on the responsive design.

- So, i think in this case we have to change only the view component of
  the application. Am i correct ?
- What all technologies are available at our disposal that we can use
  to develop an efficient mobile version of application ?

I have heard about `Spring mobile , jquery mobile` etc , but I am not sure from where to start basically i have to give a list of technologies/library/framework that can be used for the mobile web development.

Please help with your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

First I think I should caveat that this question is only going to get opinion based answers since there are many different ways to support mobile platforms from web applications and the right solution will largely depend upon what platform the majority of your end users will be using and the amount of content you need to display.

If the majority of your users will be pc/tablet based but you also want to support mobiles with the one application then you should take a look at the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) css framework which provides an easy way to create a responsive UI which will look usable on most screen sizes however it won't look like a native mobile app, which from my experience is where jquery/spring mobile have the advantage they make web apps look like native mobile applications although whilst they can viewed on a pc/tablet they won't look great scaled up.

In my experience if you want a great user experience on both mobile and pc you should create 2 separate User Interfaces each one focused on a specific platform otherwise one or other user experience will be compromised in some way.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea I am working on creating separate interfaces for the mobile, table and desktop.Right now I am going through Spring Mobile and evaluating it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As mentioned, "mobile" development is a loaded topic. Spring Mobile isn't trying to solve every problem, and isn't a framework for responsive design. But it does offer a server side device detection module so you can present different views tailored to desktop, mobile and tablet clients. You can always couple that with one of the various client-side JavaScript frameworks to create a more compelling experience.

Comment: @Roy which all other client side frameworks are available , i heard about jQuery mobile and @Jcm mentioned `bootstrap` ? is there any other that is worth looking ?

Comment: There are a number of JavaScript frameworks or libraries that offer UI elements and controls. Besides for jQuery Mobile, here are a sampling of ones I've used or am aware of: [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/), [Jo]( http://joapp.com/), [jQT](http://jqtjs.com/), and [DHTMLX Touch](http://dhtmlx.com/touch/)